# Example code on Ubuntu+node.js gives error re "await"

Tags: horizon, javascript-sdk, developersguide

Updated: added full code below.

I'm trying to run the ["Creating a payment transaction" example](https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-sdk/reference/examples.html) but the error I get is

```
const account = await server.loadAccount(sourcePublicKey);
                ^^^^^    
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

I am running this on Ubuntu 18.04 (Digital Ocean) w/ Node.js v8.10 as instructed and have edited the code so that it uses the test network and key pairs I have set up w/ the laboratory.

So what do I need to do to my setup to get this example to work, or is there a workaround using promise? I just want to do a test transfer of some lumens on the test network.

### Here's the full code - it's the same as what is provided as example code on the stellar developer site at link above. (The secret key is for a testnet address so I don't mind sharing it).

```
const StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');

const sourceSecretKey = 'SC5XS6G54A2ILNQRZF4H2MF57CPOWFNLPGGVD5NTJ7FDJA2VACTLFR7N';

const sourceKeypair = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(sourceSecretKey);
const sourcePublicKey = sourceKeypair.publicKey();
console.log('\nPublic Key derived = ');
console.log(sourcePublicKey);

const receiverPublicKey = 'GC6AESSU7M35TQEFUIVUW2G7375G5YRLIPIT7WDSJRLT5UMLI5P76F2S';

const server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org');

StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork();

const account = await server.loadAccount(sourcePublicKey);

const fee = await server.fetchBaseFee();


const transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account, { fee })
  .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
    destination: receiverPublicKey,
    asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
    amount: '350.1234567',
  }))
  .setTimeout(30)
  .build();

transaction.sign(sourceKeypair);

console.log(transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR('base64'));

try {
  const transactionResult = await server.submitTransaction(transaction);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(transactionResult, null, 2));
  console.log('\nSuccess! View the transaction at: ');
  console.log(transactionResult._links.transaction.href);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('An error has occured:');
  console.log(e);
}
```

---

Comment: Hi Peter, you got a few downvotes, this is for two reasons. First is that you dumped a huge blob of text as a question. Please format your code. Secondly, this is not a Stellar issue, it's a Node issue. Granted, the example should have probably been written differently, but had you searched for the error message you'd have gotten a clear answer on how to implement this correctly.

Comment: FYI I've raised https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-sdk/issues/246 to improve this for the future.

Comment: I see this as a Stellar issue as they provided a code example that simply didn't work. The example would have worked if it conformed to the syntax, or if the preceding text explained that this example can't be copied/pasted and instead needs further coding to enclose it in a function as others have explained. This post has at least resulted in an improvement request for the Stellar sdk docs in github. I don't see it as a Node issue as the Node/js is working exactly as it should. Thanks for formatting the code I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have described, you need to use await within an async function, so the following should work:

(Note the two comments...)

```
const StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');
const sourceSecretKey = 'SBHPB666WEISWVSIWWVBZ4RA3L7OXP53HJNT66UEJJSIERIBH2LCZSVS';
const sourceKeypair = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(sourceSecretKey);
const sourcePublicKey = sourceKeypair.publicKey();
const receiverPublicKey = 'GADJ4AWIARPTSUEN4GOXRFYSG45RMF665ZLRE6OSIDQ3DHFG44ZOFNLX';
const server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org');
StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork();

// This line
const asyncScope = async function() {
    const account = await server.loadAccount(sourcePublicKey);

    const fee = await server.fetchBaseFee();

    const transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account, { fee })
      .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
        destination: receiverPublicKey,
        asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
        amount: '350.1234567',
      }))
      .setTimeout(30).build();

      transaction.sign(sourceKeypair);

    try {
      const transactionResult = await server.submitTransaction(transaction);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(transactionResult, null, 2));
      console.log('\nSuccess! View the transaction at: ');
      console.log(transactionResult._links.transaction.href);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
}

// And this line
asyncScope();
```

Answer (score 3):

The error itself contains all the information you need for the troubleshooting.

Probably you wrapped this code in some function (i.e. `function testPayment() {...}`). To make it work, add `async` keyword before the function declaration. Like `async function testPayment() {...}`.

Documentation on async/await usage in JS can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Comment: I am simply trying to run the example code provided on the Stellar dev site as mentioned and linked in my question. I don't see where this "wrapping" is happening. It seems to be simply called outside of any function. I added the code to my question if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you can't call `await` unless you're in an `async` function. If you literally copy/pasted the example into an editor and ran it, the issue is that you aren't in a function - you're at the top level. See. e.g. number 8 in [this post](http://2ality.com/2016/10/async-function-tips.html) (quoted below). The solution is to wrap the example code in an `async` function.

> Sometimes, it’d be nice if you could use await at the top level of a
>   module or script. Alas, it’s only available inside async functions.
>   You therefore have several options. You can either create an async
>   function main() and call it immediately afterwards:

```
async function main() {
    console.log(await asyncFunction());
}
main();
```

> Or you can use an Immediately Invoked Async Function Expression:

```
(async function () {
    console.log(await asyncFunction());
})();
```

> Another option is an Immediately Invoked Async Arrow Function:

```
(async () => {
    console.log(await asyncFunction());
})();
```

Comment: Yes I copied/pasted and ran the example. I expected the example to work as it was on a very busy stellar.org code example page. Maybe that was too much to ask. I'll have to do more familiarization I guess. These options will help.

Answer (score 0):

The test script requires some basic concepts with await/async, and is not going to work with direct copy-paste.

Start with this ["create account" example](https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-base/reference/base-examples.html#creating-an-account) to familiarize yourself with the syntax. Modify `StellarSdk.Operation.&createAccount({~~})` to other operations like `StellarSdk.Operation.payment({~~})` accordingly to test things out.

Comment: Yes I copied/pasted and ran the example. I expected the example to work as it was on a very busy stellar.org code example page. Maybe that was too much to ask. I'll have to do more familiarization I guess.